# Global variables,c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I tried many solutions, but can't get my program work.

main.h

```
short NWMP_acc[3];
short NWMP_gyro[3];
```

main.cpp

```
printf_( "%i,%i,%i, g\n", NWMP_gyro[YAW],NWMP_gyro[PITCH],NWMP_gyro[ROLL]);
```

other.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
NWMP_gyro[YAW]   = (((buf[3]>>2)<<8) +  buffer[0]);//multiple definition of `NWMP_gyro'
```

If I change to "extern short NWMP_acc[3];" than I get an error "undefined reference to `NWMP_acc'"

Comment: `printf_` looks like C not C++, but very odd C at that.

Comment: You want to declare the *existence* of global variables in the header, but you need to define them somewhere in just one source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need both with and without the `extern`

In your header you need:

```
extern short NWMP_acc[3];
extern short NWMP_gyro[3];
```

But in one of your ".cpp" files you still need:

```
short NWMP_acc[3];
short NWMP_gyro[3];
```

The reason for this is that the `extern` keyword can be roughly thought of as meaning "I promise that somewhere in one file there exists an actual real thing that looks like this".

Comment: Is this variables will be available to changing from other .cpp files?

Comment: @wsevendays: Yes, because it is declared as `extern`.

Comment: @wsevendays Yes, all of the other ones places which see the `extern` declaration will use the one single definition you provide, but you must provide exactly one definition somewhere still.

Comment: @wsevendays: Yes, it will be visible as long as you don't make the definition `static`, which of course you must not do when you really want a shared global variable.

Answer (score 4):

If you **declare** the array as `extern` (which you have to if you want a global variable across translation units), you have to **define** it in exactly one translation unit. So, for example:

```
// main.h
extern short NWMP_acc[3]; // declare

// main.cpp
#include "main.h"
short NWMP_acc[3]; // define

// other.cpp    
#include "main.h"

void foo() {
    std::cout << NWMP_acc[0] << std::endl; //just use, don't define again
}
```